# Code Explanation: Enum and Rendering

Tags: java, enums, render, enum-map

So I came across this piece of code and being a beginner, i didn't really understand the code. I was wondering if someone could explain to me the code. Thanks!

```
private static final EnumMap<State, IRenderer> RENDERERS_MAP;
    static {
    RENDERERS_MAP= new EnumMap<State, IRenderer>(State.class);

   for (State state : State.values()) {
        RENDERERS_MAP.put(state, getRender());
   }
}
```

It's mainly this piece of code ^ code that i needed an explanation about because as a beginner I've never used "<>" and ":". Also I'm not sure what a EnumMap is. Preferably this one can be explained in full detail. What is IRenderer?

**EDIT:**
I also would like what <> and : are called so i can search it up on the internet and read up on them. Links are welcome too :)

```
void render() {
    Renderer currentRenderer = RENDERERS_MAP.get(currentState);
    if (ren  != null) {
        currentRenderer.render();
     }
}
```

This is the piece of code that I think renders the code onto the screen.

```
public enum State {
    START_MENU() {
        @Override
        public Renderer getRenderer() {
            return new StartMenuRenderer();
        }
    },
    PLAYER_ONE_MENU() {
        @Override
        public Renderer getRenderer() {
            return new PlayerOneRenderer();
        }
    },
    PLAYER_TWO_MENU() {
        @Override
        public Renderer getRenderer() {
            return new PlayerTwoRenderer();
        }
    },
    WIN_SCREEN() {
        @Override
        public Renderer getRenderer() {
            return null;  //TODO: implement body
        }
    },
    LOSE_SCREEN() {
        @Override
        public Renderer getRenderer() {
            return null;  //TODO: implement body
        }
    },
    PLAY_SCREEN() {
        @Override
        public Renderer getRenderer() {
            return null;  //TODO: implement body
        }
    };

    public abstract Renderer getRenderer();
}
```

This is the enum State which is being used to organize all the states in the game.

Thank you for all your help and explanations!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> It's mainly this piece of code ^ code that i needed an explanation
>   about because as a beginner I've never used "<>" and ":". Also I'm not
>   sure what a EnumMap is. Preferably this one can be explained in full
>   detail.

The `<>` is part of the generics declaration, and simply associates the types you declare to the generics class you are using.  For a `Map`, there are two types, the `Key` and the `Value`, which by convention are declared as `EnumMap<K,V>`

So when you say:

```
RENDERERS_MAP= new EnumMap<State, IRenderer>(State.class);
```

You are saying that you wish to create an `EnumMap` where the `Map` key is a `State`, and the `Map` value is an `IRenderer`.  Once you declare your particular `EnumMap` with your desired types, Java then takes care of casting when retrieving or setting values on the `Map`.

So you can say:

```
IRenderer myRenderer = RENDERERS_MAP.get(myState);
```

without explicitly casting.

Answer (score 2):

1,EnumMap is a Map whose key is an Enum;

2, for(State state : State.values())... is an convenient form of iterating all item in State  enum;

3,<> is generic type in Java,like template in C++,It means the specific Type will be descided in runtime,

4,the last piece of code looks like  [State pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/State_pattern):different state,different implementations

Comment: Generics is for type-safety which is enforced by the compiler.

Comment: Yes,in this example,forced the V to be an IRenderer,the specific type will be descided in Runtime.

Comment: IMO, the specific type here is `IRenderer` and it's decided at the compile-time. In Java, generics is not available at runtime due to type-erasure.

Comment: @BheshGurung what is IRenderer

Comment: In generics terms it's called the actual type argument. [`EnumMap<K extends Enum<K>,V>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/EnumMap.html) is how the class is declared, where `K` and `V` are the formal type parameters.

Comment: I figured out that Generics is a compile level technics,the compilor force Map<State,IRenderer> to only accept State as Key,IRenderer as Value,while .java is compiled to .class,all generic information is erased.

Answer (score 1):

EnumMap is a specialized Map implementation for use with enum type keys. All of the keys in an enum map must come from a single enum type that is specified, explicitly or implicitly. Here the Enum is State.

Now, in this line

```
RENDERERS_MAP= new EnumMap<State, IRenderer>(State.class);
```

You create an object of type EnumMap where State Enum is used as key. It is enclosed within <> because State could be replaced with any other Enum also. <> Suggests that that type is Generic. You can use any other enum in place of State.

Next,

```
for (State state : State.values()) {
        RENDERERS_MAP.put(state, getRender());
   }
```

This For loop is used for iterating all the EnumMap values One by one just as we iterate array elements one by one. ":" is used for iterating in many languages. Its a part of Syntax of Java foreach loop. In this loop Key and values are assigned for each index of RENDERERS_MAP using the put Method.

Comment: IRenderer is a common interface for all the renderers. You can refer to the following links for all the details regarding renderer : http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/faces/render/Renderer.html